# Send JS two-dimensional array over AJAX into Laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass two-dimensional array a simple PHP reads file. It's does not contain any Eloquent model query or so.

This is my little source code of order.js:

```
$("#sendData").click(function()
{
    $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/orders/example",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {request: linePosition},
    }).done(function(msg){
        console.log(msg)
    }).fail(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    });
});
```

This is my PHP ProductController:

```
public function example(Request $request)
{
    return json_decode($request);
}
```

This is my web.php routes:

```
 Route::get('/orders/example','ProductController@example');
```

This is error stored in console.log when I try to send data:

```
responseJSON: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
message: "No query results for model [App\Order]."
status: 404
```

I don't understand why try to "perform query" to model. Just only try to get array data values of this ajax.

Laravel 5.6.
jQuery 3.3.1

Comment: If you want to send data use 'POST' not 'GET'

Comment: I added route with POST and change in ajax.
Is freaky, now tells:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`
My array does contain "name" or "id", just only have an 0,1,2.. index with values "Lemon","Type"... or so

Comment: hard to say anything without knowing structure of data you are sending, can you log it plz?

Comment: I uploaded src code in https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/BYCGtOaZ6jGUiNdE-Wtj4g

Comment: Just SOLVED.

You have to create a new route BEFORE of `Route::resources`, with:
`Route::get('/orders/create','OrderController@example');`
switch jQuery AJAX into POST not GET.

Thanks ! :D

Comment: cool.. yeah GET is to send more of query parameters